# Getting HttpException on 302 redirect in my response

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp

```
Api.initOAuthDiscoverConfig("url")
                .flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<String> apply(String jsonString) throws Exception {

                        Log.i(TAG, " initOAuthDiscoverConfig " + jsonString);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                        String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                        String state = nonce.split("-")[0];
                        return Api.initOAuthLogin(jsonObject.getString("authorization_endpoint") + "?" +
                                "scope=" +
                                "response_type=code&\n" +
                                "client_id=" +
                                "redirect_uri=" +
                                "state=" + getAlphaNumericString(12) + "&" +
                                "nonce=" + getAlphaNumericString(10) + "&" +
                                "prompt=login");
                    }
                }).flatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<String> apply(String authLoginString) throws Exception {
                Log.i(TAG, " initOAuthLogin " + authLoginString);
                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create("loginForm=loginForm&" +
                        "javax.faces.ViewState=stateless&" +
                        "loginForm:username=" +
                        "loginForm:password=" +
                        "loginForm:loginButton=Sign In", MediaType.parse("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded*"));
                return Api.OAuthLoginForm("url", requestBody);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String loginResponseString) {
                        Log.i(TAG, " OAuthLoginForm " + loginResponseString);
                        hideProgress();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "onNext called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        hideProgress();
                        showAlertDialog(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong), false);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "onError called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        HttpException error = (HttpException)e;
                        String errorBody = error.response().errorBody().toString();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError: "+ errorBody);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

**its going into onError everytime, instead of onNext in subscribeWith . Dont know where its going wrong. Appreciate any help.**

Based on what i understand I think theres some issue in DisposableObserver. (Maybe i am wrong).

P.S:- not much experienced with Rxjava

Comment: OkHTTP (which is the HTTP handler of Retrofit) handles 302 redirect and as such shouldn't make it to the application layer. [Source](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1694). What is the response code that you get from the `HttpException` in `onError`?

Comment: @Shankha057 it shows Response code 302

Comment: You can try to use a `Single` or `Flowable` instead of an `Observable` and then implement failure handling logic there as a stream

Comment: is there anything to do with "subscribeWith"? theres a warning saying its always ignored. Will that be of any problem ?

Comment: The warning is probably is something like "the result of `subscribeWith` is ignored. Don't worry about it. It basically means that the method returns some value but since you are not returning it or assigning it to a variable, it's return value is getting ignored.

Comment: Can you please print the message of the exception in `onError` callback? Because even though OkHTTP handles redirect automatically (unless you have explicitly disabled it while building the `Retrofit` object), you may have been having some kind of error in one of the stages above which gets propagated when downstream and hence you are seeing the error even though you should not trigger the `onError`.

Comment: You should start with cleaning up all the boilerplate anonymous classes and replace then with lambdas. Then clean up the `flatMap`s by taking the `jsonBody` and `requestBody` creation outside the chain, as variables. Then debug the your code and see where there is some kind of exception that is thrown. Replace all async methods with blocking methods and then place breakpoints all over the place and see where there is some kind of exception or error being thrown. And then update the question. Reactive streams are quiet difficult to debug.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/e84e3a2d397be1dc937783352d57a39c7c244a05/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Response.java#L41) method over here is interesting. Debug and see if this method is getting called internally somewhere after you receive the redirect response. If such is the case then that method is throwing an exception because of your code being 302. And the workaround I can think of is by using a `Flowable` and then implementing retry logic using functions like `onErrorResumeNext` or `onErrorReturn`

Comment: let me try that out. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on talk in comments implementing `onErrorResumeNext` function, solved the issue.